# Motor map using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I´m trying to do a motor map, also called onion plot, I done it by hand and I am not entirely happy with the results. The red curves should be bigger each time and the right hand side grow more. Is there some way to do this more or less automatic?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xmin=600,   xmax=2000,
    ymin=0,   ymax=2500,
    xlabel={rev [$rpm$]},ylabel={Torque [$Nm$]},
        height=9cm,
        width=9cm,
        grid=major
    ]
        

    \addplot+[ultra thick,no markers] coordinates {
            (700, 600)
            (850, 900)
            (1100, 2200)
            (1450, 2200)
            (1600, 2000)
            (1800, 1850)
            (1950, 550)
    };

    \addplot+[thick,no markers, smooth,tension=0.8] coordinates {
            (950, 1400)
            (1050, 1000)
            (1190, 990)
            (1260, 1500)
            (1200, 2000)
            (1100, 2200)
    };
    \addplot[thick,no markers, smooth,tension=0.9,red] coordinates {
            (910, 1200)
            (1100, 750)
            (1400, 1100)
            (1600, 2000)
    };
    \addplot[thick,no markers, smooth,tension=0.4,red] coordinates {
            (860, 960)
            (1000, 650)
            (1200, 550)
            (1500, 1000)
            (1750, 1880)
    };


    \node[fill=white] at (1250,1300) {\footnotesize 190 $g/kWh$};
    \node[fill=white] at (1400,1100) {\footnotesize 195};
    \node[fill=white] at (1500,1000) {\footnotesize 200};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by “The red curves should be bigger each time and the right hand side grow more.“? Do you maybe have a graph that looks like your desired outcome?

Comment: To put it differently, the left hand side of the curve should be more or less parallel the righthand side should be diverging, just as the example above.

Comment: What about using always the same x-values and the the y-values as a parameter?